# How to make a dynamic plot in Python?

Tags: python, plot

I have temperatures that are being read by a thermocouple. Readings are taken every second for 60 seconds. Is there a way to get every iteration to plot as the values are being taken?

I.e, can I get a plot that will plot every temperature every second as it is being read?

Comment: Use any plotting library like matplotlib..

Comment: Other candidate: *[Realtime plotting in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213291)*

Answer (score -1):

One solution would involve [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) and its `animation` function. You can find a simple tutorial with demo [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/).